# packages contaning gazebo plugins

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can anyone provide me packages similar to rrbot_package so that i can check them. I want to see how others packages containing gazebo_plugins are used for communicate to ros and how they r making their gazebo ros packages so.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15027/packages-contaning-gazebo-plugins/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Helllo:

To find more examples of how other packages are using `gazebo_plugins` you could use

- Use the [github search engine](https://github.com/search?l=XML&q=gazebo_plugins&ref=simplesearch&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)
- Go to the [gazebo_plugins ROS wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_plugins) and click in the link "Used by". Explore the links that will appear there.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2016-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0